# Route [admin.departments.index] not defined

Tags: laravel

i am trying to return back to departments after add a new department but this what happens :

Route [admin.departments.index] not defined

this is my store function in the DepartmentController

```
class DepartmentController extends BaseController
{
  public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'department_name'      =>  'required|max:191',
    ]);

    $params = $request->except('_token');

    $department = $this->departmentRepository->createDepartment($params);

    if (!$department) {
        return $this->responseRedirectBack('Error occurred while creating department.', 'error', true, true);
    }
    return $this->responseRedirect('admin.deparments.index', 'Department added successfully' ,'success',false, false);
}
```

}

this is the responseRedirect function in the base controller

```
 class BaseController extends Controller
 {
  protected function responseRedirect($route, $message, $type = 'info', 
   $error = false, $withOldInputWhenError = false)
     {
    $this->setFlashMessage($message, $type);
    $this->showFlashMessages();

    if ($error && $withOldInputWhenError) {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput();
    }

    return redirect()->route($route);
   }
}
```

these are the routes

Route::group(['prefix'  =>   'departments'], function() {

```
        Route::get('/', 'Admin\DepartmentController@index')->name('admin.departments.index');
        Route::get('/create', 'Admin\DepartmentController@create')->name('admin.departments.create');
        Route::post('/store', 'Admin\DepartmentController@store')->name('admin.departments.store');
        Route::get('/{id}/edit', 'Admin\DepartmentController@edit')->name('admin.departments.edit');
        Route::post('/update', 'Admin\DepartmentController@update')->name('admin.departments.update');
        Route::get('/{id}/delete', 'Admin\DepartmentController@delete')->name('admin.departments.delete');

 });
```

InvalidArgumentException
Route [admin.deparments.index] not defined.

Comment: Always check for the typo first and copy and paste the errors, not write it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The `store` function in your DepartmentController returns a typo: `admin.deparments.index` should be `admin.departments.index`.